# Append to Global List<String> using another List<String> in Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I am working on an Android App and about the complete it. There is one problem I am facing currently, at least for now.

I am taking user selection from ListView multiselection from different Activities and then storing it in Global List successfully. The only issue is, it sets the last selection as the Global List

Below is further explanation just to elaborate my point. I cannot paste the code as it is complicated so thought it is better to explain this way.

---

I have 3 Activities. Each Activity has got a unique Title. In each Activity, there are ListView with values. I have made the user selection (for the sake of understanding) bold in each activity.

Activity 1 - Title **Fruits**
List

1. Fruit 1
2. **Fruit 2**
3. **Fruit 3**
4. Fruit 4

Activity 2 - Title **Vegetables**

1. **Vegetable 1**
2. Vegetable 2
3. **Vegetable 3**

Activity 3 - Title **Meat**

1. **Meat 1**
2. Meat 2
3. Meat 3
4. **Meat 4**
5. Meat 5

Now when I store the selection using below code, it works perfectly fine.

```
int count = 0;
int size = list.size();

List<String> fruits_selection = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
    if (list.get(i).isSelected()){
        count++;

        String selected_fruits_string = list.get(i).getFruit_id();

        fruits_selection.add(selected_fruits_string);
    }
}

Global globalSelectedItems = (Global)getApplicationContext();
globalSelectedItems.setSelected_items_gv(selected_fruits_string);
```

This same code is applied in all the activities with just "fruits" being replaced by the title in the proper format.

So this gives me the result of the last activity's selection and not all. I know it is obvious and why it is giving me this result.

---

So the result I am getting is:

```
Meat 1, Meat 4
```

Whereas I want:

```
Fruit 2, Fruit 3, Vegetable 1, Vegetable 3, Meat 1, Meat 4
```

Can anyone help me in appending the new selection from next Activities to globalSelectedItems?

Comment: What does `globalSelectedItems.setSelected_items_gv()` do?

Comment: After all the selections, I will take this to a PHP file and store the user selection into database. `globalSelectedItems.setSelected_items_gv()` is actually setting the value of `Global List<String>` based on the user selection.

Comment: Based on your question, the purpose of that method should be to aggregate data from all Activities, in case it's just setting the value to the selection from the last Activity - its behavior is incorrect. It should do smth like `globalItems.addAll(localItems)`, and not `globalItems = localItems`, right?

Comment: You have got my point. The behaviour right now is expected. I know what I am doing and I expect the result what is coming as I don't know how to use or what to use list clone, copy and so on...

Comment: As I mentioned, if you want to add items from `listLocal` to `listGlobal`, do `listGlobal.addAll(listLocal)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So this gives me the result of the last activity's selection and not
>   all.

try this

```
 public class HealthyUDXB_Order extends Application { 
private List<String> selected_items_gv= new ArrayList<String>(); 

public List<String> getSelected_items_gv() { 
return selected_items_gv; 
} 

public void setSelected_items_gv(List<String> selected_items_gv) { 
this.selected_items_gv.addAll(selected_items_gv); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Since I have dynamic number of repetition of these activities based on the database, so I cannot use static variable. That is one of the reasons I mentioned that it is not possible to paste the code. I thought it is better to pass on the values to activities ahead via Global List. Now I just need to append to the list.

Comment: Static variable should be present in the Application class, not in your Activity Class. do you get me? @MohammedAkhtarZuberi

Comment: Since I am not as experience as you are, therefore I may not be getting what you are trying to say. Kindly explain.

Comment: ok. leave it. you can pass it via intents. thats the better option

Comment: Oh, I think I got you. I have created a class with the name Global and defined in Manifest file as the Application Name. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Intents are not the option for me as I have a very complex data to transfer. That is the reason I am using this method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137814/discussion-between-mohammed-akhtar-zuberi-and-darish).

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much brother.